# Transform and insert millions of records into multiple tables using powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, powershell-3.0

Retrieved 1 million records from a table using powershell. Need to transform all these 1 million records and then insert into another parent table along with some child tables.
I am able to do this using for-each loop (for every record, transform and then insert) but taking tens of hours. Tried the below approach mentioned in the below URL but it didn't help much.
[Building batch insert statement powershell to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641722/building-batch-insert-statement-powershell-to-sql)

Is there any alternative way to resolve the issue using powershell?
Please see the below sample code snippet where dataset from table[0] contains 1 million records which are iterated using ForEach

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] | ForEach {
    $VALUE1 = $_.VALUE1
    $VALUE2 = $_.VALUE2
    $VALUE3 = $_.VALUE3
    $VALUE4 = $_.VALUE4
    $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO PARENT_TABLE([column1],[column2],[column3],[column4]) VALUES (@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4);
        INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE1([column1],[column2],[column3]) VALUES (@col1,@col2,@col3);
        INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE2([column1],[column2],[column3]) VALUES (@col1,@col2,@col3);"        
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $InsertQuery
    $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@col1", $VALUE1) | Out-Null
    $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@col2", $VALUE2) | Out-Null
    $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@col3", $VALUE3) | Out-Null
    $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@col4", $VALUE4) | Out-Null
    $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: What is the database you're using?

Comment: I forget where I read it, but assigning to ```$null``` is apparently a *tiny* bit faster than piping to ```out-null```. It might not make *much* difference, but if you’re doing it millions of times they’ll add up, and it’s an easy change… ```$null = $SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@col1", $VALUE1)```

Comment: If the tables are in the same database then you should definitely not do it this way. Instead write a database script to do it, it'll be far faster

Comment: There is a [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach), a [`Foreach-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) and a [`.foreach()` method](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/12/10/foreach-method-in-powershell.aspx) but afaik, a `For-Each` statement doesn't exist. What did you really try here? Anyways, I think you should resolve this on a pure `SQL` level using the [`Join`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) clause (I have added `SQL` to the tags.)

Comment: @JamesZ We are using Microsoft SQL Azure

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you should be able to use [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) with the Azure version too. I'd expect that to be significantly faster from the database side than executing 3 million insert statements

Comment: @mclayton Thanks for sharing good inputs. It would definitely add up. I am looking for the way if we could implement using powershell with batches for these million records. As most of them stated, SQL script is one of the option though.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for your inputs. Will try db script if I don't see any alternatives. Thank you!!

Comment: @iRon I am using foreach and it was a typo. Thanks for your inputs, I would look into it.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy will work.  See eg https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-SQLBulkCopy.ps1

Comment: If your tables are in the same Azure SQL database, and you are running this powershell script on-premises, then a SQL script should definitely be your _first_ choice not your second choice.

Comment: Thanks for your responses JamesZ and David Browne !!! Able to achieve it using SQLBulkCopy and datatables. Here I loaded the data from source into datatables(after data transformations). Using SQLBulkCopy, loaded data from datatables into destination tables. I tried this for 7k records and it took 15 seconds for the bulk insertion where as my previous approach for 7k records took more than an hour.